# Aligning a login form (with error text) using CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, web

I'm hoping this will be a simple one to solve.  I'm trying to create a login form that will look like this:

Email ...... | text box | error text 
Password | text box | error text

The issue I'm having is that the CSS (inline-block) used to line up the text boxes is forcing the error text onto a new line.  So I get:

Email ...... | text box 
error text 
Password | text box 
error text

This is the code so far:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">

  <p>
    <label for="email">Email </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value=""> </input>
    <div class="error"> Email Error </div> 
  </p> 


   <p>
    <label for="password">Password </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value=""> </input>
    <div class="error"> Password Error </div> 
  </p>  

  <input type="submit" value="Login">  

</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form
{
  display: inline;
}

p label
{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 60px;
}

p input
{
  width: 150px;
}

.error
{
  color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CF76f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use span instead of div tags to display error

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen in your fiddle that your div tag generates extra 'p' tag or it renders outside 'p'.
I changed your 'div' tag to 'span' and it seems to be working fine.

Update your **HTML** as mentioned below :

```
<form method="post">

  <p>
    <label for="email">Email </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value=""> </input>
    <span class="error"> Email Error </span> 
  </p> 


   <p>
    <label for="password">Password </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value=""> </input>
    <span class="error"> Password Error </span> 
  </p>  

  <input type="submit" value="Login">  

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standard solution. First you can use float:left instead of inline-block, both solutions are ok. You don't need to put your form inline. Also pushing div in p is not really "elegant".

http://jsfiddle.net/CF76f/12/

```
<form method="post">

    <div class="field">
        <label for="email">Email </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
        <div class="error"> Email Error </div> 
    </div> 

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Password </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
        <div class="error"> Password Error </div> 
    </div>  

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />  

</form>
```

```
div.field {
    clear:both ;
}

div.field label {
    display:block ;
    width: 60px ;
    clear:both ;
    float:left ;
    padding-right:10px ;
}

div.field input {
    width: 150px ;
    display:block ;
    float:left ;
}

div.field div.error {
    color:red;
    display:block ;
    float:left ;
    padding-left:10px ;
}

input.submit {
    clear:both ;
    margin-top:10px ;
}

.clear { clear:both ; font-size:0 ; overflow:hidden ; height:0 ; }
```